# Avoid rounding with std::setprecision

Tags: c++, c++11, rounding

the following example

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    std::stringstream ss;
    ss << std::fixed << std::setprecision(5) << 4567.9000990;
    cout << ss.str() << endl;
}
```

And when I run it the output is:

```
4567.90010
```

I was expecting the output: **4567.90009**

Is there any way to avoid rounding in this situation?

Thanks in advance

Comment: take a look at https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/fenv/feround

Comment: Oh guys, you are amazing!!! I was googling but it seems that I wasn't good enough... Thank you very much, this anwer my question @scohe001